# Java: SQL date format

Tags: java, oracle, date

Is there any to assign SQL date directly instead of converting through `SimpleDateFormat` and parse to sql date. I am reading few date fields from a file lets say 03/09/2017 and I also have its oracle equivalent format defined as a field definition `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I am reading the date and its format through Java and inserting to Database. Currently I am assigning the date format to `SimpleDateFormat` and parsing the date read from file and converting to SQL date as follows.

```
SimpleDateFormat YMDFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy"); 
// This is not hardcoded field. 
// Its field definition will be directly assigned as defined. In this case it is mm/dd/yyyy
Date date;
String datefield="03/09/2017";
date=YMDFmt.parse(datefield);
java.sql.Date sqldt= new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Here my problem is due to varying formats, mm is treated as minutes in java where as it is month in oracle. I will have to change to 'MM' to make it work in java but in my scenario i dont know the original format of date. i will have to read the format and parse accordingly? Please advise if there is anyway to just convert oracle format to equivalent java format (mm/dd/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy and so on) or any other solution. Thank you.

Comment: Of course you'll have to know the format of the date that you're reading from a file. As far as database is concerned, there's no date format there. Databases store date as Unix timestamp, that's a number (Number of milliseconds from Epoch, in GMT). So when reading from the database you're not reading a formatted string, but a Date object (timestamp), there's nothing to format there.

Comment: The format in Oracle has nothing to do with the format you use to parse. You should set your date format according to the format in the file. If you don't know what that is, you can't expect to get the correct values from that file.

Comment: A `DATE` column in the the Oracle database has **no** "format". You should pass the date value as an instance of `java.sql.Date`  through a `PreparedStatement`. There is no need to deal with any date formats when dealing with values from the database.

Comment: I don’t get the part about the varying formats. Are you saying that the file may contain either, say, 03/31/2017 or 31/03/2017 for 31 of March? If so, how do you determine which? I also don’t understand why you’re concerned with Oracle’s format.

Comment: As an aside, if you can use Java 8, you should probably prefer to use `LocalDate` instead of `Date`, it’s generally much nicer to work with. If you have a sufficiently new JDBC driver, you should be able to hand it a `LocalDate` instance directly (so I have heard).

Comment: @RealSkeptic : I know the format but that has been defined according to Oracle standards as mm/dd/yyyy. So i have the date string read from file and format as mm/dd/yyyy with me which is what i am having that problem in java

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Thank you for the comments. Yes date in oracle has no format but the string i am reading is defined in oracle specific formats such as 02/20/2016 is tagged to mm/dd/yyyy. Now i have the format in hand but is not actually java format to process.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your input and as i mentioned i have the field name and its equivalent oracle format in hand. so i dont have to determine which format is that. the problem comes when i process that in java alone. Thanks for additional input on localdate and we still use java 7 :(

Comment: This is why I tend to use libs like Hibernate for database work. It abstracts out these silly details. However, I would encourage you to drop java.util.Date and its friends as quick as possible and use only the java.time.* classes.

Comment: I think I am starting to get it. If you have a string `oracleFormat`, would `oracleFormat.replace("mm", "MM")` solve your problem? If you have only day, month and year, and day and year letters agree, i can’t see there’s anything to add?

Comment: If you have Java 7 and a JDBC driver that doesn’t accept a `LocalDate`, the value of the `java.time` classes is getting limited. If you want, you can still use them through the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/), though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database is Oracle, you can change your prepared statement so that it includes a `TO_DATE` call instead of the date itself.

So, if your current insert statement is something like

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO foo (datefield) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

And you use something like `stmt.setDate(1,sqldt)` to fill in the value, then you can change it into something like

```
String sql ="INSERT INTO foo (datefield) VALUES (TO_DATE(?,?))";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

And use

```
String oracleFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"; // Not hard-coded in real life
String dateStr = "03/09/2017";      // Not hard-coded in real life
stmt.setString(1,dateStr);
stmt.setString(2,oracleFormat);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

In this case, Oracle will convert the string into a date for you, instead of having Java do that.

Pay attention to changing all the other parameter numbers to fit.